# Duplicate calls when using concatMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables, concatmap

I want to display in a view the next upcoming event a user is registered to.

To do so I need first to retrieve the closest event (in time) the user is registered to and then retrieve the information of this event.

Has the list of event a user is registered to is dynamic and so is the event information I need to use two Observable in a row.

So I tried to use concatMap but I can see that the getEvent function is called 11 times... I don't understand why and how I could do this better.

Here is my controller

```
//Controller
    nextEvent$: Observable<any>;

      constructor(public eventService: EventService) {
        console.log('HomePage constructor');
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        // Retrieve current user
        this.cuid = this.authService.getCurrentUserUid();
        this.nextEvent$ = this.eventService.getNextEventForUser(this.cuid);
      }
```

The EventService (which contains the getEvent function called 11 times)

```
// EventService
getEvent(id: string, company?: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
    let comp: string;
    company ? comp = company : comp = this.authService.getCurrentUserCompany();
    console.log('EventService#getEvent - Getting event ', id, ' of company ', comp);
    let path = `${comp}/events/${id}`;
    return this.af.object(path);
  }

  getNextEventForUser(uid: string): Observable<any> {
    let company = this.authService.getCurrentUserCompany();
    let path = `${company}/users/${uid}/events/joined`;
    let query = {
      orderByChild: 'timestampStarts',
      limitToFirst: 1
    };

    return this.af.list(path, { query: query }).concatMap(event => this.getEvent(event[0].id));
  }
```

And finally my view

```
<ion-card class="card-background-image">

    <div class="card-background-container">
      <ion-img src="sports-img/img-{{ (nextEvent$ | async)?.sport }}.jpg" width="100%" height="170px"></ion-img>
      <div class="card-title">{{ (nextEvent$ | async)?.title }}</div>
      <div class="card-subtitle">{{ (nextEvent$ | async)?.timestampStarts | date:'fullDate' }} - {{ (nextEvent$ | async)?.timestampStarts | date:'HH:mm' }}</div>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <img class="sport-icon" src="sports-icons/icon-{{(nextEvent$ | async)?.sport}}.png" item-left>
      <h2>{{(nextEvent$ | async)?.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{(nextEvent$ | async)?.sport | hashtag}}</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="navigate" isActive="false" item-left small></ion-icon>
      <h3>{{(nextEvent$ | async)?.location.main_text}}</h3>
      <h3>{{(nextEvent$ | async)?.location.secondary_text}}</h3>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="time" isActive="false" item-left small></ion-icon>
      <h3>{{(nextEvent$ | async)?.timestampStarts | date:'HH:mm'}} - {{(nextEvent$ | async)?.timestampEnds | date:'HH:mm'}}</h3>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this.af.list(path, { query: query }).concatMap(event => this.getEvent(event[0].id))` is a *cold* `Observable`. This means that each time you perform a subscription on it, it will re-execute the underlying stream, which means re-calling the `getEvent` method.

`async` implicitly subscribes to the `Observable`, which is why if you count up `(nextEvent$ | async)` calls in your template, you will see where the 11 comes from.

**&tldr;**
You need to share the subscription to the stream:

```
this.nextEvent$ = this.eventService.getNextEventForUser(this.cuid)
   // This shares the underlying subscription between subscribers
   .share();
```

The above will connect the stream the first time it is subscribed to but will then subsequently share that subscription between all of the subscribers.

Comment: Thanks paulpdaniels! I actually noticed the 11 async pipes but was afraid that it would just be a coincidence. What is the purpose of these cold Observable? Would the switchMap avoid to share the subscription? I would like to avoid going through a too complex implementation for the moment.

Comment: @ManuelRODRIGUEZ no `switchMap` wouldn't fix the issue. The idea of cold `Observables` is functional purity, essentially that each time you perform an operation with a set of arguments you should expect to receive the same answer. Obviously in the real world that isn't always realistic, hence why operators like `share` exist, to convert cold `Observables` into hot ones, for scenarios just like this.

Answer (score 0):

RXJS's `concatMap` method flattens all the events into one observable. You are probably better off using the `switchMap` method. switchMap subscribes only to the most recent observable.

So doing something like this would probably solve your problem:

**Before:**

`return this.af.list(path, { query: query }).concatMap(event => this.getEvent(event[0].id));`

**After:**

`return this.af.list(path, { query: query }).switchMap(event => event);`